# Why is my array gone after exiting loop?

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bash: can’t build array in right side of pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656013/bash-cant-build-array-in-right-side-of-pipe)

I need to create an array from a file. I have to calculate an index where to store data. When I get outside my read loop, my arrays seems to be gone. Why???

The script below illustrates the problem.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "15\n21\n33" | while read i ; do
    ar[$i]="set"
    echo ${!ar[@]}
    echo ${ar[@]}
  done

echo
echo outside loop:  
echo ${!ar[@]} 
echo ${ar[@]}
```

As you can see in the output, printing the array indexes and content no longer work outside of loop.

```
15
set
15 21
set set
15 21 33
set set set

outside loop:
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/11656013/1030675

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Answer (score 8):

@ormaaj has the answer in his comment: don't put the loop in a pipeline. I assume those numbers aren't constant, so redirect from a process substitution instead:

```
while read i ; do
    ar[$i]="set"
    echo ${!ar[@]}
    echo ${ar[@]}
done < <(process to generate indices)
```

Another choice is to put the final echo statements in the same subshell as the loop:

```
process to generate indices | {
    while read i ; do
        ar[$i]="set"
        echo ${!ar[@]}
        echo ${ar[@]}
    done

    echo
    echo outside loop:  
    echo ${!ar[@]} 
    echo ${ar[@]} 
}
```